# Choose customer group on checkout in Magento

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I was searching for a way to make the customers choose customer group on checkout using a selectbox or such. Haven't found any useful articles on this subject. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

copy `config.xml` from `/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/` to `app/code/local/Customer/etc/` and modify like below ( add group_id node ):

```
<fieldset>
    ...
    <customer_account>
    <email><create>1</create><update>1</update></email>
    <group_id><create>1</create><update>1</update></group_id> 
    <!-- add above line -->
    </customer_account>
    ...
</fieldset>
```

Open `register.phtml` from `/app/design/frontend/[YOUR_TEMPLATE]/customer/form/` and add the following code block somewhere which the field that you want to appear :

```
<div class="input-box">
   <label for="group_id"><?php echo $this->__('Your customer group') ?>
      <span class="required">*</span>  
   </label>
   <select name="group_id" id="group_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('Customer Groups') ?>" class="validate-group required-entry input-text" />
   <?php $groups = Mage::helper('customer')->getGroups()->toOptionArray(); ?>
   <?php foreach($groups as $group){ ?>
       <option value="<?php print $group['value'] ?>">
           <?php print $group['label'] ?>
       </option>
   <?php } ?>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't this on registration? I want this on the checkout for a customer.

Comment: yes, you are right but as you know, if a customer has not been registered, they should be register first in checkout, except guest.

Comment: Yeah, of course. In my case I would like the registered customer to able the choose to have a different customer group in checkout. Is that possible?